# Eclipse finds a bug but I don't see it

Tags: java, eclipse

I wanted to make a decimal to binary converter in Java. I tried this code (down here) but "Eclipse" says

> System.out.println (y);

has a problem. it says:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
>   Unresolved compilation problem:   y cannot be resolved to a variable

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dtb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myscanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        int num= myscanner.nextInt();
        int base= myscanner.nextInt();  
        int i = 0;
        while (num >= base) {
            int x = (num % base);
            num = num / base;
            int y = 0;       
            y = (y + (x * (10 ^ i)));
        }

        System.out.println (y) ;
    }
}
```

I didn't see any problem but Eclipse does not operate it.

Comment: So post the actual error message. Eclipse doesn't just say "you have a problem".

Comment: Have you ever heard about `scope` of variables?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yMAvmUyrwlc&list=PLhQjrBD2T382Lqs7bsMl6WRDA9anaEzBe#t=2285) will help a little.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, if you say you have an error **Post it here**

This may solve the problem you have

```
public class dtb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //You do not declare y;
        int y=0;

        while (num >= base){
            int x = (num%base);
            num = num/base;        
            y = (y + (x*(10^i)));   
        }    
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is formatted very poorly which makes the problem hard to see:

```
while (num >= base){
        int x = (num % base);
        num = num/base;
        int y=0;         
        y = (y + (x*(10^i)));   }

 System.out.println (y) ;
}}
```

Notice that there is a end brace at the end of the line that changes the value of `y`

If you reformat your code so that braces are on their own lines and scope is properly indented:

```
    while (num >= base){
        int x = (num % base);
        num = num/base;
        int y=0;         
        y = (y + (x*(10^i))); 
     }

     System.out.println (y) ;
    }
}
```

You can see that your `println` call that uses `y` is outside the scope of the y variable.

you probably want to put the print inside the while like this:

```
  while (num >= base){
        int x = (num % base);
        num = num/base;
        int y=0;         
        y = (y + (x*(10^i))); 

         System.out.println (y) ;
     }

    }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the meaning of `y`. It seems he is doing a summation, so outside of the loop would probably be more correct.

Comment: not when the line above it is y=0 ?

Comment: I think he meant to put it outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Because you declare y inside the while loop, you cannot use it outside of it. So when you try to print y afterwards, it thinks that you haven't declared that variable yet. To fix this, move your initial declaration of y outside the while loop, like so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class dtb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = myscanner.nextInt();
        int base = myscanner.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (num >= base) {
            int x = (num%base);
            num = num/base;
            y = (y + (x * ( 10^i )));
        }
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

Also, good formatting helps.